# Can't find opensession() exception for Hibernatetemplatein hibernate5.1 and spring 4.1.6 integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using `hibernate 5.1.0` and `spring 4.1.6` jars. For `Hibernate 3.6` jar, it's working fine, but i don't want to downgrade my hibernate jar. So what is the solution for `hibernate 5.1` and `spring 4.1.6` integration?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
```

***My applicationcontext.xml file:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="admin"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

    <property name="mappingResources">  
    <list>  
    <value>author.hbm.xml</value>  
    </list>  
    </property>  

    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
             <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
             <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
             <prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop>

        </props>  
    </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">  
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="authorDAO" class="com.dao.AuthorDAO">  
<property name="template" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>  
</bean>
```

***My entity class:***

```
package com.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Author implements Serializable   {

private Integer authorID;

private String authorName;

public Integer getAuthorID() {
    return authorID;
}

public void setAuthorID(Integer authorID) {
    this.authorID = authorID;
}

public String getAuthorName() {
    return authorName;
}

public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
    this.authorName = authorName;
}
```

}
***My author.hbm.xml :***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
 <class name="com.hex.vo.Author" table="AUTHOR31668">  
      <id name="authorID">  
      <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
      </id>  

      <property name="authorName"></property>   
 </class>  

</hibernate-mapping>
```

***My DAO Class:***

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;

import com.hex.vo.Author;

public class AuthorDAO {

HibernateTemplate template;  

public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
    this.template = template;  
}
public HibernateTemplate getTemplate() {
    return template;
} 

//method to save Author  
public void saveEmployee(Author e){  
     template.save(e);  
}  
//method to update Author  
public void updateEmployee(Author e){  
    template.update(e);  
}  
//method to delete Author  
public void deleteEmployee(Author e){  
    template.delete(e);  
}  
//method to return one Author of given id  
public Author getById(int id){  
    Author e=(Author)template.get(Author.class,id);  
    return e;  
}  
//method to return all employees  
public List<Author> getEmployees(){  
    List<Author> list=new ArrayList<Author>();  
    list=template.loadAll(Author.class);  
    return list;  
}
```

}

***My Testclient Class:***

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.dao.AuthorDAO;

import com.vo.Author;




   public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] arg){      

        Author author= new Author();
        author.setAuthorID(123);
        author.setAuthorName("Prava");

        ApplicationContext context = 
                 new   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        AuthorDAO dao=(AuthorDAO)context.getBean("authorDAO");  

        dao.saveEmployee(author);  
     System.out.println("Saved successfully..");



    }
}
```

Comment: why the Author class does not have @Entity?
Can you share the author.hbm.xml file?

Comment: You are using Hibernate5, but you are using Hibernate4 and hibernate3 classes in your code and configuration. You should use the ones from the package that match your hibernate version.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa ya. i fprgot to add author.hbm.xml file.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  
  
<hibernate-mapping>  
<class name="com.hex.vo.Author" table="AUTHOR31668">  
          <id name="authorID">  
          <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
          </id>  
            
          <property name="authorName"></property>   
</class>  
            
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. I wll modify n try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `HibernateTemplate` of version 3 with hibernate 5. this is incompatible.

Also `HibernateTemplate` is deprecated. you should consider changing to sth else.

Please have a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) article

Comment: So HibernateTemplate can map to entity without the annotation @Entity?

Comment: `HibernateTemplate` is old enough, it went together with the old hbm.xml mapping as you commented before. I'm not sure if it is compatible with the annotation-way, havent used it for years actually! See the link i posted, too. It definitely says to go the Hibernate 5 way and it guides you on how to do that. `HibernateEntity` shouldnt be used in new projects.

Comment: "with the old hbm.xml" as far as I know hbm configuration still widely used for hibernate , specially for mapping properties with spring, am i wrong?

Comment: well, yes ok there are many legacy projects that still use the old xml mapping format, but the new style is annotated classes. Even in web projects we try to remove web.xml file, if possible. The trend is xml-less. :)

Comment: thank you, these are useful info , guess i need to do some dig up on that, I am voting the answer as myself got enough useful info

Comment: @Apostolos I have changed to hibernate4. rectified the mistake. now m getting Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.

Comment: @Apostolos as per the shared link, they are using org.springframework.orm.hibernate5 which is available in spring4.3.2. but i am using spring4.1.6 and hibernate5.1.0 . So these versions can be integrated or not..??

Comment: @Prava, there are lots of stackoverflow threads about the FlushMode error.  In order to use this class, you have to upgrade to at least spring 4.2. spring 4.1 has only support till hibernate 4.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 4.1.6 supports hibernate 3 and hibernate 4. So for integrating hibernate 5 with spring, use spring 4.3 jar(latest jar) where spring-orm jar is having hibernate5 support.